# Access Violation Exception: Call unmanaged function from C# code

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, unmanaged, access-violation

I have an unmanaged Delphi? library and I try to call an unmanaged function from C# code, which requires allocated memory to write to. I try to allocate memory in the C# code and then I face the problem of Access Violation Exception.

1.From the doc I know that the calling convention of the function is StdCall. My target platform is x64 and I don't know whether it's useful  info.

2. I've googled and tried to solve the problem with the Marshal.X functions, but they didn't help. Now the signature in the C# code looks like this:

   ```
    [DllImport(@"lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

     internal static unsafe extern int Reg(
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string host,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string port, 
           char arm,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string username,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string password,
           void* answer, 
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int abufsize);
   ```
3. Then I call it with the Marshal allocation and get the Access Violation.

   ```
         unsafe
            {

               var answer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char)) *
                     BUFSIZE).ToPointer();

               rcode = Wrapper.Reg(_config.Host, _config.Port, _arm, 
                   _user.Username, _user.Password, answer, BUFSIZE);
            }
   ```

Original signature is

```
      function reg(host: Pchar;
      port: Pchar;
      arm: char;
      name,password: Pchar;
      var answer: Pchar; abufsize: integer):integer;
```

Now I don't know how to deal with Access Violation and have no idea what exactly causes the problem.

**UPD:** The same function can be called and performs correctly with the different parameters and returns error code, but when it tries to write to the buffer, it crashes, so the problem is connected with the memory.

**SOLVED:** Finally I've solved the problem using *ref* keyword in my C# signature. Amazingly.

```
     [DllImport(@"lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
         CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

      internal static unsafe extern int Reg(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string host,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string port, 
            char arm,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string username,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string password,
            ref byte* answer, 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int abufsize);
```

Comment: It could be anything, starting from incorrect params and ending with code error inside "reg" function. Try to start from calling any simple function like "procedure test(host: Pchar);" and watch what is wrong.

Comment: See an update, the problem is still with memory.

Comment: No need for unsafe here

Comment: Furthermore, ask your self why you are allocating a buffer, and passing its length, and then letting the callee overwrite that pointer, and return its buffer? Something is badly wrong with this interface. It smells all wrong.

Comment: An interface of a library doesn't belong to me, but I have no idea why you consider this "wrong".Can you explain me your position?